# Join tables from two different database Oracle and postgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have two databases on different servers.

Server1

Oracle database:

Table teacher

```
                 uuid                 | name  
--------------------------------------+-------
 835167f2-23c6-409d-a83b-573905465f53 | David
```

Server2

PostgreSQL database

Table student

```
                 uuid                 | name |              teacher_id              | teacher_name 
--------------------------------------+------+--------------------------------------+--------------
 57475f51-0fb2-4cea-9eba-9a31ae7f9492 | Tom  | 835167f2-23c6-409d-a83b-573905465f53 |
```

I want to update table student column teacher_name according to table teacher that has same teacher uuid. How to do it?

Comment: have a look at Foreign data wrappers for postgres, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html

Comment: You can use a foreign data wrapper from Postgres to Oracle

Comment: Which  database is driving the process.  If the process is being driven from the Postgre database, then as others have said, 'foreign data wrapper'.  If the process is being driven from the oracle database, then you need to create a database link and configure the Oracle Transparent Gateway for ODBC.